# How Can I Display a N x N Matrix of Random Numbers in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, for-loop

I'm trying to create a matrix of random double numbers. The matrix must be of size n x n and all numbers must be between 1 and 100. I've been trying to sort it out for ages now and I know it must be something so simple (as it usually is).

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    PrintRandomGraph(RandomArray(4));
}

private static double[] RandomArray(int n) {  
    double[] randomArray = new double[n];
    double[][] randomMatrix = new double [n][n];

    Random rand = new Random(); 
    rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        Integer r = rand.nextInt()% 100; 
        randomArray[i] = Math.abs(r);
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            Arrays.fill(randomMatrix, i, i+1, randomArray);
        }  
    }

    return randomArray;  
}

private static void PrintRandomGraph(double[] inputArray) {
    int n = inputArray.length;
    double[] showArray = new double[n];
    double[][] showMatrix = new double [n][n];

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            double r = inputArray[i];
            showArray[i] = r; 
            Arrays.fill(showMatrix, i, i+1, showArray);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(showMatrix));
}
```

When I run the code I get a random array repeated n times like :

> [[63.0, 97.0, 64.0, 75.0], [63.0, 97.0, 64.0, 75.0], [63.0, 97.0, 64.0, 75.0], [63.0, 97.0, 64.0, 75.0]]

I think I need to go back to the top  of the for loop and add the new array...? Please help =(

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: could you reformat your printRandomGraph() function?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure. I was messing about with this earlier but I kept just printing out the same four numbers in different orders or with blanks in places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all this provides the answer I was looking for

```
 private static double[][] RandomArray(int n) {
        double[][] randomMatrix = new double [n][n];
        double[] randomArray = new double [n];
         Random rand = new Random(); 
            rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis()); 

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   

            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                Integer r = rand.nextInt()% 100; 
                randomMatrix[i][j] = Math.abs(r);
            }

        }

        return randomMatrix;
    }


public static void main(String[] args){

        //PrintRandomGraph(RandomArray(5));
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(RandomArray(5)));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try something like this:

```
private static double[][] RandomArray(int n) {
    double[][] randomMatrix = new double [n][n];

    Random rand = new Random(); 
    rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {     
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            Integer r = rand.nextInt()% 100; 
            randomMatrix[i][j] = Math.abs(r);
        }

    }

    return randomMatrix;
}
```

to Print the graph:

```
public void printGraph(double[][] array, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {     
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.println(array[i][j]);
        } 
    }
}
```

To Print Graph with Square brackets:

```
public void printGraph(double[][] array, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
            System.out.print(" [ ");   
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j]);
            } 
            //Put println instead of print here to have each row in a new line
            System.out.print(" ]");
        }
    }
```

Also, this seems a lot like homework, if it is, please tag it like so :)

Comment: minor amendment: nextInt() % 100 gives non-uniformly distributed results between 0 and 99. If you want a better random distribution, use `nextInt(100) + 1`. That will give uniformly distributed results between 1 and 100.

Comment: I've just realised that I've done something stupid... My return type on randomArray should be a matrix not an array...! 

I then have to iterate through the matrix in printGraph and pull the elements out??

Comment: I think that you were over complicating things if you just wanted to print the array contents.

Comment: I've tried your code and it works, thank you =). It just prints everything down the screen instead of the regular format with the square brackets?

Comment: Hi Tamara, I have edited my response so that you can get the square brackets. I used println, so it basically prints the text and moves the cursor one line down.